# Error: Unable validate connection VS Code and Prophet extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on salesforce project. I'm trying to upload the code using Prophet tool. Unfortunately it is not working and throwing HTTP Authentication error like

```
Unable validate connection!
Please check your credentials (login, password, etc)
Error: Error: 401
```

But with the following credentials I can login in the browser. Only problem is not able to upload.

**Note** Same configuration it is working fine in other laptop. What could be the issue?

Here the configuration model for **dw.json**

```
{
    "hostname": "xxxxx",
    "username": "xxx",
    "password": "xxxxx",
    "version" : "xxxx"
}
```

**Tools**

```
Visual Studio code version 1.48.2
Prophet extention version 1.13.23
```

**Error Info**'
[image]

Comment: Strange but I fixed by using Forgot Password option and changing the password.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and it was related to my BM access/role.
So, you have to recheck your BM access/role to your sandbox or ask the administrator about this.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have one explain your solution and provide as an answer otherwise any such observations can be put into comments.